# find all values from text a in text b and type next to it other column from other file with awk

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, statistics

a.txt

```
xa,xono a,y,z,abc
xb,u,v,def
xc,w,x,ghi
xd,a yuli x,c,u,jkl
xe,u,v,w,x,y,z,mno
xf,z,u,p dao,pqr
```

b.txt

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
.....(etc)
21,u
22,v
23,w
24,x
25,y
26,z
27,xono a
28,a yuli x
29,p dao
30,...
31,abc
32,def
33,ghi
34,jkl
35,mno
36,pqr
```

Now the second column values in b.txt, i want to find if they exist in a.txt, if yes we write next to the second column in b.txt(or in other file) the first column in the a.txt to obtain a such file like:

```
1,a
2,b
3,c,xd
4,d
.....(etc)
16,p
.....(etc)
21,u,xb,xd,xe,xf
22,v,xb,xe
23,w,xc,xe
24,x,xc
25,y,xa,xe
26,z,xa,xe,xf
27,xono a,xa
28,a yuli x,xd
29,p dao,xf
30,...
31,abc,xa
32,def,xb
33,ghi,xc
34,jkl,xd
35,mno,xe
36,pqr,xf
```

Comment: Take a look at `man join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `gawk` version 4.1 you can use arrays of arrays. Try

```
gawk -F, -f s.awk a.txt b.txt
```

where `s.awk` is:

```
NR==FNR {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        a[$i][$1]++
    next
}

{
    keys=""
    if ($2 in a) {
        for (i in a[$2])
            keys= keys","i
    }
    print $0 keys
}
```

Explanation:

- We use a new feature introduced in `gawk` version 4. Called "arrays of arrays", see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Arrays-of-Arrays
- The keys from `a.txt` are first stored in an array `a`. For instance, a["xono a"]["xa"], is one element in the array.
- For `b.txt` we then simply check if `$2` is within `a`. If so, we generate the set of keys that belongs to this value..
- `print $0 keys` is string concatenation of `$0` and `keys`, that is `print ($0 keys)`

Comment: i like the solution but it doesn't match look what it display for the duplicated strings u,v,w,x,y,z :
21,uxd
22,vxb
23,wxc
24,xxc
25,yxa
26,zxa
and it should display :21,u,xb,xd,xe,xf
22,v,xb,xe
23,w,xc,xe
24,x,xc
25,y,xa,xe
26,z,xa,xe,xf

Comment: Clear and simple and awsome ! thank you ! explanation for keys and print $0 keys ? we concatenate the value each time we find the string thats right ?

Comment: i've tried it with awk (not gawk) and it works too .. is that normal ? and the last question: -F -f is for what ??

Comment: @user3057111 I am sure about that I have both Gnu Awk version 3.1.8 and version 4.1.0 installed. It does not work with verson 3.1. What do you get if you type `awk --version`?

Comment: @user3057111 It is not `-F -f`. It is `-F,` first, with set the field separator to `,`, then `-f s.awk` tells awk to read script from file `s.awk`.

Comment: you are right .. it's 4.01 but what's the difference between awk and gawk then ?

Comment: @user3057111 Maybe you have `gawk`.. I am using linux (Ubuntu 12.04) and `awk` is just an alias for `gawk`. If you type `awk --version` you can check if you have `gawk` or not. For a list of the different versions, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations

Comment: yeah .. it's GNU Awk 4.0.1 .. i won't waste your timer longuer .. and thank you one more time

Comment: sorry for bothering you .. i couldn't understand this line  for (i in a[$2]) :( a[$2] will contain what exactly ?

Comment: @user3057111 It contains the keys. For instance, `a["u"]` is an array with elements `"xe"`,  `"xf"`, `"xb"`, `"xd"`.. So you can say for instance `a["u"]["xe"]`..

Comment: @user3057111 `i` is here an array index. Its value is changing for each iteration of the `for` loop. For instance, for the case above when `$2="u"`, `i` will take on the values `"xe"`, `"xf"`, `"xb"`, and `"xd"` for each iteration..

Comment: now it's better.. only this i didn't understand why we use the for ? it adds what exactly to the result ?

Comment: @user3057111 We use the `for` loop to print all indices.. For instance, first iteration `i` is equal to `"xe"`, and then `keys` become `",xe"`, next iteration `i` is equal to `"xf"` and `keys` is updated to become `",xe,xf"` and so on...

Answer (score 4):

BASH/awk solution:

```
IFS=, && while read -r p q; do awk -v p="$p" -v q=",$q" -F, 'BEGIN{
     printf "%s%s", p, q; gsub(/\./, "\\.", q); r=q"(,|$)"}
     $0 ~ r{printf ",%s", $1; next} END {print ""}' a.txt; done < b.txt
1,a
2,b
3,c,xd
4,d
.....(etc),
21,u,xb,xd,xe,xf
22,v,xb,xe
23,w,xc,xe
24,x,xc,xe
25,y,xa,xe
26,z,xa,xe,xf
27,xono a,xa
28,a yuli x,xd
29,p dao,xf
30,...
31,abc,xa
32,def,xb
33,ghi,xc
34,jkl,xd
35,mno,xe
36,pqr,xf
```

Comment: Sure. while loop used `IFS=,` to use each value from `b.txt` into shell vars `p and q`. Then `p and q` are passed to awk as arguments. Awk then searches each line from `a.txt` using `,a`, `,b` etc and if it is found those values are printed. `print` statements in BEGIN/END for printing argument and new line.

Comment: still dont understand .. whats the difference between the first printf and the second one and index($0,q) is for what exactly ? -v ? %s%s to print $p and $q ?

Comment: `printf in BEGIN` is for printing `"1,a", "2,b", "26,z"` etc and 2nd printf is for printing `",v" ",xb" ",xe"` etc. Whereas `awk -v p="$p" -v q=",$q"` is awk way of passing shell variables to awk.

Comment: im sorry.. it doesn't match.. i didn't describe precisely what i have as example, i have edited the question.. the problem that it displays all the occurrences of the searched value even it is in the word..

Comment: `i didn't describe precisely` Describe clearly for which lines in output my answer doesn't match your algorithm.

Comment: okay.. if we take the example in the question i've edited it again .. and we execute the command we will have for example 

16,p,xf (because p exists in a.txt in xf,z,u,p dao)
 
1,a,xd (because a exists in a.txt in xa,xono a,y,z)

so what i need is that he dont diplay any value occurence. i want that he display only the string between the two comma ..

Comment: i want that he display exactly the string between the two comma

Comment: yeah :D you are great man ! thank you very much ! so what did you add the ~r ? is for what ?

Comment: `$0 ~ r` is actually regex match since I create `var r` as `,p(,|$)` which means `,p` is either followed by comma or end of line.

Comment: i have another problem --" , i added "..." in the b.txt , and i added on each line in a.txt a word with three letters , in the result it displays 30,...,xa,xb,xc,xd,xe,xf .it search each with three letters and displays it, but what i want is that it display 30,... because there isn't a string mathing "..."

Comment: ok check the update and request you to not to change the problem requirements further :)

Comment: sorry for wasting your time .. and thank you very much .. i found the solution of Håkon Hægland is more interesting .. take a look.. one more time .. thank you

Comment: Yes I have seen that solution but since it required awk 4+ version I cannot test it locally since my awk is on OSX and that is not 4+

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking for `awk`, and yes, that's possible. Perhaps you can write that yourself based on this implementation in `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %mapping;

open(my $a, 'a.txt');
while (<$a>) {
    chomp;
    my ($xx, @letters) = split(/,/);
    foreach my $letter (@letters) {
        if (!exists($mapping{$letter})) {
            $mapping{$letter} = [];
        }
        push(@{$mapping{$letter}}, $xx);
    }
}

open(my $b, 'b.txt');
while (<$b>) {
    chomp;
    my ($num, $letter) = split(/,/);
    if (exists($mapping{$letter})) {
        print join(',', $_, @{$mapping{$letter}}), "\n";
    } else {
        print $_, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^([^,]+)(,[^,]+)|/^[^,]+\2,?/s/$/,\1/\n\1|;/,/P;D' a.txt|sed -rf - b.txt
```

This builds a sed script from `a.txt` which is run against `b.txt`.